# why firestore doesnt upgrade while firebase realtime database updated

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

i am building a chat app using firebase in one of my vuejs app...in this system I want to show the status of user which are active/inactive...So for that I used the solution of firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence which can be found here..SO far i try this. The Realtime database is updated but cloud firestore is not updated. Please help me..I will very helpful.

```
let user = this.profile.id;
            let base = database.ref("/online_users/" + user);
            var store = db.doc('/status/' + user);
            var isOfflineForFirestore = {
                state: 'offline',
                user_id: user,
            };
            var isOnlineForFirestore = {
                state: 'online',
                user_id: user,
            };
            var isOfflineForDatabase = {
                state: 'offline',
                user_id: user,
            };
    
                var isOnlineForDatabase = {
                    state: 'online',
                    user_id: user,
                };
    
                database.ref('/online_users/'+this.profile.id).on('value', function(snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.val().state == 'offline') {
                        // Instead of simply returning, we'll also set Firestore's state
                        // to 'offline'. This ensures that our Firestore cache is aware
                        // of the switch to 'offline.'
                        store.set(isOfflineForFirestore);
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                    }
    
                    base.onDisconnect().set(isOfflineForDatabase).then(function() {
                        store.set(isOnlineForFirestore);
                        base.set(isOnlineForDatabase);
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference on how you initiate RTDB and Firestore. It's not fully included on your code but you should pay attention on how you create a reference. Unlike on RTDB where you use `firebase.database().ref()`, on Firestore, you create a document reference using `firebase.firestore().doc()`.

Try this:

```
var store = firebase.firestore().doc('/status/' + user);
```